# Object is losing event handlers after being stored / retrieved from Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, events

Similar to [DataTable saved to Session state loses event handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833605/datatable-saved-to-session-state-loses-event-handlers) although the recommended solution there did not apply.  I am not serializing Session data.  Objects are being kept InProc.

I have a class called `Application` with these relevant bits:

```
public class Application {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private Lazy<Asset> _asset;

    public String AssetId { get; set; }

    public Application() {
        RestoreEventHandlers(new StreamingContext());
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void RestoreEventHandlers(StreamingContext context) {
        PropertyChanged += AssetId_PropertyChanged;
        PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AssetId"));
    }

    private void AssetId_PropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.PropertyName == "AssetId")
            _asset = new Lazy<Asset>(() => new Asset(AssetId));
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null) {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The goal is for `_asset` to get reset whenever the related `AssetId` property changes.  I need to keep the `AssetId` and `Asset` records synchronized.  I have verified that the event is called after an object is created the first time.

After an application is created I am putting it in Session like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentApplication"] = application;
```

On subsequent requests I am getting it from Session like this:

```
var application = HttpContext.Current.Session["CurrentApplication"] as Application;
```

This is being called from a helper class which is why I need to use the static objects to get the current request context.

Later in the same method I have a line that does this, if the user has asked to change the asset on the application:

```
application.AssetId = assetId;
```

After this assignment the event handler is not invoked.  If I write it this way instead it works as intended:

```
application.RestoreEventHandlers(new StreamingContext());
application.AssetId = assetId;
```

Something is causing my event handlers to become unbound.  Any ideas?

Comment: The last 2 code snippets are the same, did you mean to put something else in the last one?

Comment: @Rhumborl Yes, good catch.  Sorry about that.  I meant to show that if I am not explicitly calling `RestoreEventHandlers` then the event will not fire.  I don't want to have to call that explicitly because the whole point is for client code to be blissfully unaware of that mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be way out here, but is the `PropertyChanged` event being invoked at all, other than in `RestoreEventHandlers()`? I had it in mind that you need to raise it manually inside the property - see example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

```
private string _assetId;

public string AssetId
{
    get
    {
        return _assetId;
    }
    set
    {
        _assetId = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Of course you could just reset the `_asset` inside the property:

```
private string _assetId;

public string AssetId
{
    get
    {
        return _assetId;
    }
    set
    {
        _assetId = value;
        _asset = new Lazy<Asset>(() => new Asset(AssetId));
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right - it was not being invoked at all.  Perfect solution, thank you!